# Phalcon: How to get resultset and total over limit

Tags: php, phalcon

How to achieve this query in phalcon using query builder (best method):

```
$results = "select * from table where name like 'A%' limit 10"; // <-- 10 records

$total = "select count(1) from table where name like 'A%'"; // <-- 100 records

return [
    'data' => $result,
    'total' => $total
];
```

im extjs user and i need to get total over limit to display paging information (eq: displaying 1 to 10 from 100 records)

thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with `Pagination`, see here: [Pagination Docs](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/pagination.html#adapters-usage)

Only thing is to use `QueryBuilder` adapter. But this can be done with:

```php
$builder = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
    ->from('Table')
    ->andWhere('name like :name:', array('name' => 'A%' ) );

$paginator = new Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\QueryBuilder(array(
    "builder" => $builder,
    "limit"=> 10,
    "page" => 1
));

return [ 
    'data' => $paginator->items,
    'total' => $paginator->total_items
];
```

Comment: omg, I think pagination tend to display html. so I am not paying attention. thanks for the knowledge

Comment: sorry for asking u again, could i use `offset` instead of `page` parameter in paginator options?

Comment: Hi, as far as I know the docs there is only `page` parameter so you must calculate `page` from given `offset` and `limit` (I'm assuming that ExtJS requests anther page with offset and it should give you also 'limit' value).